# Need advice on how to design this. Composition or inheritance?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm trying to design a client / server solution. Currently it contains three projects. The client, the server, and a library that each use (because they both require a lot of the same stuff).

For example, both the client and the server (in this case) read incoming data in the exact same way. Because of this, both the client and the server have their own `MessageReader` object. The `MessageReader` will first read the first 4 bytes of incoming stream data to determine the length of the data and then read the rest. This is all performed asynchronously. When all the data is read the class raises its own `MessageRead` event or if there was an `IOException` while reading it raises its own `ConnectionLost` event.

So this all works fine. What's the problem? Well, the client and the server are a bit different. For example, while they may read data in the same way, they do not write data in the same way. The server has a `Dictionary` of clients and has a `Broadcast` method to write to all clients. The client only has a single `TcpClient` and can only `Write` to the server. Currently all this behavior is within each respective WinForm and I want to move it to a `Client` and `Server` class but I'm having some problems.

For example, remember earlier when I was talking about the `MessageReader` and how it can raise both a `MessageRead` event and a `ConnectionLost` event? Well, now there's a bit of a problem because in designing the `Client` class I have to capture these two events and re-raise them because the client form should not have access to the `MessageReader` class. It's a bit ugly and looks like this:

```
class Client
{
    private MessageReader messageReader = new MessageReader();

    public delegate void MessageReceivedHandler(string message);
    public delegate void ConnectionLostHandler(string message);

    public event ConnectionLostHandler ConnectionLost;
    public event MessageReceivedHandler MessageReceived;

    public Client()
    {
        messageReader.ConnectionLost += messageReader_ConnectionLost;
        messageReader.MessageReceived += messageReader_MessageReceived;
    }

    private void messageReader_MessageReceived(string message)
    {
        if (ConnectionLost != null)
        {
            ConnectionLost(message);
        }
    }

    private void messageReader_ConnectionLost(string message)
    {
        if (MessageReceived != null)
        {
            MessageReceived(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is ugly because its basically duplicate code. When the `MessageReader` raises the `MessageReceieved` handler the `Client` has to capture it and basically re-raise its own version (duplicate code) because the client form should not have access to the message reader.

Not really of a good way to solve it. I suppose both `Client` and `Server` could derive from an abstract `DataReader` but I don't think a client **is a** data reader, nor is the server. I feel like composition makes more logical sense but I can't figure out a way to do this without a lot of code duplication and confusing event handlers.

Ouch, this question is getting a bit long.. I hope I don't scare anyone away with the length. It's probably a simple question but I'm not really sure what to do.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the responsibility of the Client class?  What job is it designed to accomplish?  If all it is is a pass-through for MessageReceived and ConnectionLost events, then you might be better off using an interface to achieve the decoupling you're looking for.  Otherwise, answering that question may help us suggest a better approach.

Comment: @Nimrand: The Client class can connect to a server given a hostname and a port, maintain a listening thread for when the server sends it messages, and send messages to the server. Its member variables are a `TcpClient` and the `MessageReader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using inheritance for this even though the relationship wasn't strong. The code duplication it got rid of was worth it. Was able to place all the events both classes shared in to the base class.

Comment: Getting rid of inheritance doesn't mean code duplication, it means just not using inheritance. You could still separate the code into objects and use aggregation (with DI) to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Composition.

I didn't even read your code or text. I find that the average developer (almost) never needs inheritance but they like to use it quite a bit.

Inheritance is fragile. Inheritance is hard to get correct. It's harder to keep it in check with SOLID.

Composition is easy to understand, easy to change, and easy to DI, Mock, and test.

[SOLID](http://www.davesquared.net/2009/01/introduction-to-solid-principles-of-oo.html)

Comment: Yes, I am currently using composition but as you can see from reading the provided code sample, it is causing me some problems.

Comment: Yea, just downvote me. That's too verbose and complicated to read.

Comment: @Ryan - I didn't say that you did.